# Почему при расшифровании файла считываются не все символы из закодированного файла?

Tags: c++, шифрование

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
if (OpenDialog1->Execute() )
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromFile (OpenDialog1->FileName) ;

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
int q=0;
char ch;
char mas1[8];
char mas2[8];
char mas3[8];

char gam[8] = {'П', 'k', 'O', 'Q', 'б', 'я', 'Y', 'v'};
ifstream infile(OpenDialog1->FileName.c_str());
ofstream outfile("Ofile.txt");
while(!infile.eof())
{
++q;
int i;

for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
  infile.get(ch);
 if(!infile.eof())
  {
   mas2[i]=ch;

  }
  else
  break;
 }

if(q==1)
{
 for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
  {

   mas3[j] = mas2[j] ^ gam[j];
   outfile.put(mas3[j]);

   }
   }
   else
   {
    for(int c=0; c<i; ++c)
    {
     mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];
     outfile.put(mas3[c]);
     }
   }
  for(int w=0; w<i; ++w)
  {
   mas1[w] = mas3[w];
   }
   }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::BitBtn3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
int q=0;
char ch;
char mas1[8];
char mas2[8];
char mas3[8];
char gam[8] = {'П', 'k', 'O', 'Q', 'б', 'я', 'Y', 'v'};
ifstream infile(OpenDialog1->FileName.c_str());
ofstream outfile("File.txt");
while(!infile.eof())
{
++q;
int i;
for(i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
 infile.get(ch);
 if(!infile.eof())
  {
 mas2[i]=ch;
 }
 else
 break;
 }
if(q==1)
{
 for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
  {
   mas3[j] = mas2[j] ^ gam[j];
   outfile.put(mas3[j]);
   }
   }
   else
   {
    for(int c=0; c<i; ++c)
    {
     mas3[c]=mas2[c] ^ mas1[c] ^ gam[c];
     outfile.put(mas3[c]);
     }
   }
  for(int w=0; w<i; ++w)
   {
    mas1[w] = mas2[w];
    }

   }
}
```

С файлами формата `.тхт` работает хорошо. Но когда открываю файл `.rtf`, шифрование происходит без ошибок (по размеру совпадают), а вот при расшифровывании файла, при попытке открытия через MSWord выдает сообщение что файл поврежден. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Отформатируйте нормально код,пожалуйста

Comment: А теперь подойдет?

Comment: Открывайте файлы в binary mode (см., например, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)

Comment: Там четкого примера нет. А как в binary работать с циклами?

Comment: @ВладимирСамофал остальное ничего не меняется, просто добавьте аргумент `ios_base::binary` в вызовы конструкторов обоих потоков.